# Flutter - Textfield/keyboard issue whenever clicking on special characters button

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield

Whenever I type into a text field and click on the special characters button & then try to edit past text by clicking in between some of the letters, it'll automatically highlight all of the text instead of showing the original single cursor sitting between 2 letters. This can be a bit annoying and confusing for the user experience. Is there any quick fix for this?

Note: I'm using a real device (Samsung Galaxy S8)

Here are 2 images to better explain this problem:

Trying to edit text before clicking on special characters button:
[image]

Trying to edit text after clicking on special characters button:
[image]

Comment: Add the code of this output